# cant read updated xml file that stored in server

Tags: android, xml

i am facing problem , and i realy need help , i am storing xml file in my server , my android application try to read the data from inside the xml , the reading process works perfectly but the problem when i try to change the data inside the xml file , the android application still read the previous old data and cant read the new ones , i noticed something that when i try to clear data from setting and then re-reading xml file , my app read the new data in the xml ,and i want to say something that the same code i tested it on rss ,the code works perfectly and read the new data without any problem 
plz help 
sorry bad english